# iOS - Deal with Async task that point to a deallocated variable

Tags: ios, memory-management, asynchronous, block

I'm calling an asynchronous function from my controller and I pass to it a reference to an error variable, let's say:

```
NSError *err=nil;
[self myAsyncTask:&err];
```

if the controller get deallocated, the err variable does not exist anymore, so the app crash with a BAD_ACCESS error (because the function try to change the value of the err variable). How can I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that none of the built-in framework methods use pass by reference error reporting with asynchronous calls - they all use delegation or blocks to communicate error status. Using blocks, your API could be written to be used like:

```
[self doAsyncTaskWithErrorHandler: ^(NSError *error) {
    //Handle error
}];
```

The method signature could look like

```
- (void)doAsyncTaskWithErrorHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorHandler;
```

And in the implementation, where you used to do `*error = someError;` do something like:

```
NSError *error = ...;
if (errorHandler) {
    errorHandler(error);
}
```

If I'm not mistaken this isn't really an issue with object lifetime though - if the stack frame is popped before the error is set then the pattern in the question would likely cause a crash as well.

Comment: Lots of heads exploded, and unfortunately you can't weed the scanners from the crowd.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I deal with that?

If you have an asynchronous function in process, you have to ensure that any variables that it uses remain valid until that function completes. Objective-C's memory management lends itself nicely to this -- a method like your `-myAsyncTask` can retain its arguments until it no longer needs them. That way, even if the controller (to use your word) is deallocated, the objects referred to by the variables will remain valid.

Another way to do it is to use a block for the async functionality. Blocks automatically retain the resources that they use, so they effectively solve this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about blocks, so I guess with the solution of @carl I'll solve my problem?